# Partition function for Gaussian white noise

Tags: statistical-mechanics, path-integral, partition-function, noise, stochastic-processes

## Problem

I'm trying to understand, motivate, or derive from first principles, the partition function for gaussian white noise, namely

$$
Z = \int \mathcal{D}\eta(t)\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2D}\int dt \eta(t)^2\right].
$$

I thought I could work out the steps, but I'm unable to pass to the continuum limit from the discrete case.

## My attempt

I assumed that, for gaussian white noise on a lattice (discrete points in time), the probability of a noise of any amplitude $\eta(t_i) = \eta_i$ is given by
$$
P(\eta_i) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi D}}\exp\left(-\frac{\eta_i^2}{2D}\right).
$$
I am stuck trying to pass to the continuum limit from here. If you try to calculate the partition function from this, you get
$$
Z \stackrel{?}{=} \left(\frac{1}{2\pi D}\right)^{N/2}\prod_i^N \int d\eta_i\exp\left(-\frac{\sum_i^N \eta_i^2}{2D}\right).
$$
But ideally you'd have an epsilon in the exponent so that you could do

$$
\epsilon \sum_i \eta_i^2 \rightarrow \int dt \eta(t)^2.
$$

Could someone help steer me in the right direction? Thanks for any help.

Comment: For clarity, I suggest you explain your notation, ie. What is $\eta$ and what is $D$ in this case?

Comment: $\mathcal{D}\eta(t)$ is the path integral measure, and the factor of $-1/2D$ is the conventional normalization for the correlation function, so that $\langle \eta(t) \eta(t') \rangle = 2D\delta(t-t')$. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: What does the partition function for a particular noise mean? Is this the partition function associated to the probability for each trajectory of the stochastic process?

Comment: @DanielSank yes. In the sense that the partition function is the sum of all probabilities $p_i$, where $i$ indexes a particular state. I think I could have been clearer about what I meant, but I'm not totally familiar with the terminology yet. "The sum over all probabilities where each probability is associated with a trajectory of a stochastic process" seems to be what I'm looking for, but it's a bit of a mouthful.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I'm interested in stochastic processes, but I'm not an expert. I wanted to make sure I understood this question so I can learn from it.

Comment: Criticism of notation - the partition function is not a functional of $\eta$, $\eta$ is a dummy variable in the integration on the right hand side. It is, as far as I can see, only a function of $D$. When written as a functional, it is usually a functional of the source function, $J(t)$: $$Z(D)[J] = \int \mathcal{D}\eta \exp\left(\int \left[-\frac{\eta(t)^2}{2D} + J(t)\eta(t)\right]\operatorname{d}t \right).$$

Comment: @SeanLake That's exactly right. Updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

White noise is characterised by the autocorrelation function 
$$\langle \eta(t) \eta(t') \rangle = D \delta(t-t'),$$ 
(here I'm assuming that $\eta$ is dimensionless so $[D] = [t]$). This means that (1) the noise should be uncorrelated with itself at different times, but also that (2) the variance of $\eta(t)$ must be **infinite**. Condition (2) is the essential missing ingredient here.

Before showing how to incorporate (2) into a discretised model of the noise, let us first motivate why we need $\eta(t)$ to have infinite variance. This is necessary in order that the integrated signal, defined by
$$ W(\tau) = \int_0^\tau{\rm d}t\;\eta(t), $$
be non-zero. Indeed, we have that
$$ \langle W(\tau)^2\rangle = \int_0^\tau{\rm d}t\int_0^\tau{\rm d}t'\;\langle \eta(t) \eta(t') \rangle = D\tau,$$
i.e. the variance of the integrated signal grows linearly with time, with "diffusion constant" $D$, just like a [continuous random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_random_walk) where the walker's position as a function of time is given by $W(\tau)$. This is no coincidence: the random variable $W(\tau)$ describes the [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process), which is fundamental to the definition of white noise. In particular, if ${\rm d}W(t) = W(t+{\rm d}t)-W(t)$, then the variable $\eta(t)$ is actually *defined* as
$$ {\rm d}W(t) = \eta(t){\rm d}t.$$

Note that if the variance of $\eta(t)$ were finite, $W(\tau)$ would vanish identically. Suppose that instead $\langle \eta(t) \eta(t') \rangle = f(t-t')$, where $f(0)$ is finite and $f(t) = 0$ for $t\neq 0$. Hence, it follows that $\langle W(\tau)^2\rangle = \langle W(\tau)\rangle = 0$. This implies that the integrated signal $W(\tau)=0$ with probability one. In other words, the finite instantaneous fluctuations of $\eta(t)$ combined with its zero correlation time leads the integrated effect of the noise signal to cancel to zero over any finite time.

In order to define the noise signal as the continuum limit of a discrete process, we start from a discrete (unbiased) random walk. In each time increment $\delta t = t_{i+1} - t_i$ the walker is displaced by the amount $\delta W_i = \eta_i \delta t$ (c.f. $ {\rm d}W(t) = \eta(t){\rm d}t$), where $\langle \delta W_i\rangle = 0$. Making each step size proportional to $\delta t$ ensures that the step size tends to zero in the continuum limit $\delta t\to 0$, so that $W(t)$ describes a continuous (nowhere differentiable) function. Moreover, each of these steps must be statistically independent in order to recover zero correlation time (white noise) in the continuum limit. We also assume that the set of steps $\delta W_i$ are identically distributed. Now, the variance of the walker position after $N$ steps, corresponding to a time $\tau = N \delta t$, is given by
\begin{align}
\langle W(\tau)^2\rangle & = \left \langle \left ( \sum_{i=1}^N \delta W_i \right)^2 \right\rangle\\
& = (\delta t)^2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^N \langle \eta_i^2 \rangle + \sum_{i\neq j} \langle \eta_i\eta_j\rangle\right) \\ 
& = (\delta t)^2 \sum_{i=1}^N \langle \eta_i^2 \rangle,
\end{align}
where the third equality follows from statistical independence of the steps: $\langle \eta_i\eta_j\rangle = 0$ for $i\neq j$.

Now, in order to recover the correct scaling $\langle W(\tau)^2\rangle = D \tau$, we must have $$\langle \eta_i^2 \rangle = D/\delta t.$$ 
The variance of the discretised white-noise variable $\eta_i$ therefore tends to infinity in the continuum limit, as required. Since we also require the noise statistics to be zero-mean Gaussian (i.e. the only non-zero cumulant is the variance), it follows that the unique probability distribution function is
$$ P(\eta_i) \propto \exp \left ( -\frac{\eta_i^2 \delta t }{2D} \right), $$
up to an unspecified normalisation constant. The correct result for the partition function follows after writing down the path integral and taking the continuum limit $\delta t\sum_i \to \int\mathrm{d} t$.

Comment: Thanks. It occurred to me to put in the $\epsilon$ (or $\delta t$) by hand, as you've done here. Do you mind elaborating on why the signal carries no power if there's no $\delta t$?

Comment: Also, I am having some trouble finding the connection between the $\delta t$ that appears in your answer and the actual lattice spacing $\delta t$.

Comment: @oscarafone Well, I don't think the $\delta t$ is really put in by hand, because it's required for consistency with the formal definition of white noise in terms of the Wiener process (see my edit). About the power: suppose that the autocorrelation function is instead given by a function $f(t-t')$, where $f(t) = 0$ for $t\neq 0$ and $f(0)$ is finite. Then any integral involving $f(t)$ vanishes, such as the [power spectral density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Power_spectral_density). I don't understand your comment about $\delta t$. Isn't $t_2-t_1$ etc. the lattice spacing?

Comment: Thanks for the edit -- I'm trying to understand. So each lattice point gets a probability distribution $p(\eta) = \exp(-\eta_i^2/2\sigma^2)$. Suppose that you now cut the lattice spacing by half. I think you're saying that $\sigma$ changes. What is the reason that the probability distribution of $\eta$ at a lattice point should change when the lattice spacing changes? [Reasoning like to yours led me to a similar idea when I tried to work this out on my own, but I was unable to justify why the lattice spacing should have an effect on $p(\eta)$.]

Comment: The reasoning depends on which definition of the white noise you want to take as the "fundamental" one. If you take the definition via the autocorrelation function as fundamental, then the variance has to go as $1/\delta t$ in order to reproduce the delta function in the limit. If you take the random walk definition as fundamental, then you need your infinitesimally small steps to have infinite variance $\sim1/\delta t$ in the limit, so that the path of the random walk (Wiener process) $W(t) = \int{{\rm d}}t\; \eta(t)$ is not zero, but still a continuous (yet nowhere differentiable!) function.

Comment: Guess your statement $[D]=[t]^{-1}$ is a typo. The dimensions of a Dirac delta is the inverse of the argument. Therefore, to get a dimensionless expression $D$ must have the same dimensions as the argument of the Dirac delta. In the rest of your answer you seem to be using it with the correct dimensions.

Comment: Don't understand why you say the variance of $\eta$ must be infinite. Power is energy per unit time. If I compute the energy over a finite duration of the noise signal with a finite variance, I'll get a finite energy. Hence, the noise signal would then have a finite power. What am I missing?

Comment: @flippiefanus Thanks for the typo and the comments. I think perhaps I shouldn't have discussed things in terms of power. What is important is that the integrated signal is non-zero, which is only possible for zero-correlated noise if its instantaneous variance is infinite. I have significantly edited the answer to emphasise the importance of the integrated signal (i.e. the Wiener process) for the definition of white noise. Hopefully the answer is now clear.

Comment: I upvoted and awarded the bounty -- the answer is good, clear, and useful to others. But it's still a little puzzling to me that the definition of the partition function for noise requires one to consider a random walk on the field. You wouldn't expect to have to consider the dynamics on an Ising lattice to derive its partition function, for example.

Comment: @MarkMitchison I suppose the intuition is that, since all of these kicks happen over an infinitely short time interval, the "kicks" that come from the field have to deliver an "infinite force" to produce a finite impulse. This may have been what you meant when you were talking about power.

Comment: @oscarafone Thanks for the bounty! Your second comment is spot on, that is exactly the intuition that I have about the variance needing to be infinite. I don't really understand your first comment though. The partition function of an Ising model is determined by its Hamiltonian, which contains all the information about the system's dynamics. But this thermal partition function involves *temperature*-dependent variables, not the time-dependent variables you are considering here. So it is no surprise that the time evolution plays a more important role for this problem.

Comment: I agree that the importance of the Wiener process in particular for the definition of white noise is quite surprising at first. I guess ultimately this just reflects the fact that the mathematical properties of this type of noise happen to accurately model a lot of physical situations that arise in practice. I don't know if there is a deeper justification than this.